# Set of all versus some

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

I was looking at the definition of a cartesian cross of two sets on Wikipedia earlier.
$A \times B = \{(a, b) | a \in A \text{ and } b \in B\}$. However, I'm not sure how this defines a proper cross. Shouldn't there be some notion that these are for all a and b? Otherwise how could we define a set that had only some of the members of A and B? A bit confused here.
The reason I ask is because in my class, my teacher defined the set E of a graph with set V vertices as:
$E = \{(u, v) | u, v \in V\}$. But this was supposed to describe all directed graphs not just fully connected ones.

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.

Comment: Specifically regarding the edges of a (di)graph: I would still infer that $E = \{ (u,v) \mid u,v\in V\} = V \times V$. This would be fine if the graph were complete. But otherwise, I think the notation is misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The definition of $A\times B$, in words, can be written as

> The set of all pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.

Here "all" comes *before* the $(a,b)$. This is standard in set-builder notation. For example, $X=\{(1,2), (1,3)\}$ can be described by

> The set of all pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a\in \{1\}$ and $b\in\{2,3\}$.

This completely defines $X$ and so

$$X=\{1\}\times \{2,3\}.$$

---

We can describe a set $Y$ containing only *some* pairs of elements of $A$ and $B$ as

$$Y\subset A\times B.$$

Can you see why?

Answer (score 1):

The set $\{(a,b) : a \in A \text{ and } b \in B\}$ is interpreted as "the set of all $(a,b)$ such that $a \in A$ and $b \in B$". It is implicit in the definition that this is for all $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.

Comment: So how would you stipulate the "the set of some $(a,b)$ such that $a \in A$ and $b \in B$"

Comment: @Dude156 “a subset of $A \times B$”